# Wittig reagent with metal–oxo bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, metal, transition-metals, wittig-reactions

Could you use the Wittig reagent to attack a metal–oxo bond and replace the oxygen with a carbene?

Specifically, is it possible for the Wittig reagent to do σ-bond metathesis with an electrophilic metal attached to an oxygen?

As I'm trying to understand the mechanism, I would really appreciate an explanation for why or why not along with the answer.